# LINQ Query Similar to SQL WHERE x IN

Tags: linq, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I have a need to create a LINQ query that returns results based on a subquery.  Not quite sure I'm wording that properly but the best way I know to ask is to show an example.  How can I turn the following TSQL query into a LINQ query (tables are same name as objects):

```
SELECT CuisineId, Name 
FROM Cuisine 
WHERE CuisineId NOT IN (SELECT CuisineId 
                        FROM RestaurantCuisine 
                        WHERE RestaurantId = @id)
```

As you can guess, I'm trying to get a list of "available" cuisines to be listed for a user to add to a list of cuisines that a restaurant offers.  The LINQ I have thus far returns ALL cuisines and doesn't take in account of the existing CuisineId's that have already been added to the other table:

I've looked all over for an example but not quite sure how to describe exactly what I need.  I looked at the MSDN reference for LINQ queries but couldn't find anything like what I need:

[MSDN LINQ Sample Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688084.aspx)

Anyone able to give me an example?

Comment: I notice you linked to the VB.NET LINQ Samples.  Specify if so.

Comment: If this is Linq to SQL, make sure you don't end up with TSQL along the lines of `where not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`. It happens all too easy. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#:

```
var query =
    from c in db.Cuisine

    where !(from rc in db.RestaurantCuisine
            where rc.RestaurantId == id
            select rc.CuisineId)
          .Contains(c.CuisineId)

    select new {
        c.CuisineId,
        c.Name
    };
```

In VB.NET:

```
Dim availableCuisines = _
    From c In db.Cuisines _
    Where Not (From rc In db.RestaurantCuisines _
               Where rc.RestaurantId = id _
               Select rc.CuisineId) _
              .Contains(c.CuisineId) _
    Select c
```

Comment: I modified your query that is exactly what I needed into VB and got the following and it returns the exact result I needed.  Thanksso much Howie!!!
<br />
Dim availableCuisines = From c In db.Cuisines Where Not (From rc In db.RestaurantCuisines Where rc.RestaurantId = id Select rc.CuisineId).Contains(c.CuisineId)
                                    Select c

Answer (score 2):

```
var cuisines = db.Cuisine.Where(c => !RestaurantCuisine.Any(
                rc => rc.RestaurantId == c.Id && rc.CuisineId == c.CuisineId);
```

Comment: Any chance of knowing how this would look in VB?  also, where does the rc come from?  I tried my best to convert this to VB and came up with the following but with no avail:



Dim cuisines = From c In db.Cuisines.Where(c >= Not RestaurantCuisine.Any(rc >= rc.RestaurantId = c.Id & rc.CuisineId = c.CuisineId))

Comment: Dim cuisines = db.Cuisine.Where(Function(c) (!RestaurantCuisine.Any(Function(rc) (rc.RestaurantId = c.Id Or rc.CuisineId = c.CuisineId))))

Comment: Close, but try: Dim cuisines = db.Cuisine.Where(Function(c) Not RestaurantCuisine.Any(Function(rc) (rc.RestaurantId = c.Id AndAlso rc.CuisineId = c.CuisineId)))

Comment: rc is short for RestaurantCuisine. It represents a single row. It's common practice to use initialisms for the parameter names of a LINQ query.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Cuisine.Where(c => !RestaurantCuisine.Select(rc => rc.CuisineID).Contains(c.CuisineID)).Select(c => c);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = (from c in Cuisine
              where !(from rest in RestaurantCuisine
                               where (rest.RestaurantID == id)).Contains(c.CuisineId)
                      select new
                                {
                                  CuisineID = c.CuisineID,
                                  Name = c.Name
                                });
```